# WIN32 CPP Creating a window 400 x 400 creates a window smaller

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, position

```
RECT WindowMainRect{ 0, 0, 400, 400 };
HWND WindowMain;
HWND WindowChild;
INT main()
{
    AdjustWindowRectEx(&WindowMainRect, WS_SYSMENU, FALSE, 0);
    WNDCLASS WindowMainClass;
    memset(&WindowMainClass, 0, sizeof(WNDCLASS));
    WindowMainClass.lpfnWndProc     = WindowMainProcedure;
    WindowMainClass.lpszClassName   = L"WindowMain";
    if (!RegisterClass(&WindowMainClass)) MessageBox(NULL, L"Error", L"Register Class Error", MB_ICONWARNING);
    WindowMain = CreateWindowEx(0, L"WindowMain", L"Window", WS_SYSMENU, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, WindowMainRect.right, WindowMainRect.bottom, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    ShowWindow(WindowMain, TRUE);
    WindowChild = CreateWindow(L"Edit", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 0, 0, 350, 350, WindowMain, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    ShowWindow(WindowChild, TRUE);
    MSG Msg;
    Msg.message = WM_NULL;
    while (Msg.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&Msg);
            DispatchMessage(&Msg);
        }
    }
}
```

The code above creates a window by 400 x 400 and adjusted by `WS_SYSMENU`.
Assumptively, the client area of this window should be 400 x 400 pixels with a 1:1 aspect ratio, 
I create a child window at (0,0) with the width of 350, and height of 350.
Although, visibly the client area is not 1:1 and is vertically stretched.
Using photoshop I counted the pixels, I expected it to be above 400 pixels vertically and 400 pixels horizontally, 
Although the results returned ~386 pixels in width, and ~394 pixels in height. 
[image: Window picture]

How do I fix this and have the client area 1:1?

Comment: `AdjustWindowRectEx(&WindowMainRect, WS_SYSMENU, FALSE, 0);`
It's right there in the code above?

Comment: @Gijahara Is the purpose here to ensure the edit control is exactly 400x400, including its borders, and properly fully encapsulate the main window client area whilst doing so? I know what is going wrong, but just want to get clarification.

Comment: The edit control should be 350x350 pixels at (0,0) in the client area,
The client area should be 400x400 pixels
and the window at the size AdjustWIndowRectEx returns

Comment: ok. I think i understand.  thanks. the use-default corner is in conflict with the adjusted main rectangle, which was stretched on all *four* sides, but you're throwing out two of those adjustments by not using left/top. To bring them back into play you can use `WindowMainRect.right - WindowMainRect.left` and `WindowMainRect.bottom - WindowMainRect.top` for the width/height respectively when creating your main window. I *think* that will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this earlier but it still didn't work, using `WindowMainRect.right - WindowMainRect.left` for the width, and `WindowMainRect.bottom - WindowMainRect.top` for the height of the main windows, the client area is still not to 1:1 aspect ratio and is stretched

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you add `WS_CAPTION|WS_BORDER` to your main window style (and rectangle adjustment) on your rig (and keep the adjustment I mentioned earlier)?

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks! I was in the middle of testing another method but that actually worked? If you don't mind explaining, why does WS_CAPTION | WS_BORDER fix the issue?

Comment: basically, bad window style, and AdjustWindowRectEx was failing. WS_SYSMENU must be combined with WS_CAPTION for both that adjustment *and* the actual window creation. See [window styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles). Was guilty myself for not checking my return results ([6th commandment violation](https://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html))

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you very much! I really appreciate your help, have a good day